# How can I fix a Gem deprecation Issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, gemfile

I ran `bundle install` and it was successful. However, when I ran `ruby script/server`, I got a lot of messages before the server actually started:

```
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.

NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.

NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the deprecation is within rubygems itself.

Simply run this in console to update it:

```
   gem update --system
```

Comment: got this error while trying to update Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.11.gem)

Comment: ya i tried sudo gem update --system but thats when i get this error.. am not using rvm and i think the problem is with the gem source server.. may be il have to give some other source!! Not sure if that will work

Answer (score 0):

No one will like this, but so far, it works for me.

versions:

ruby -v  #=> ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]

rails -v #=> Rails 2.3.5

gem -v   #=> 1.8.25

The fix:
sudo vi /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb

(the file might be located elsewhere on your system, read your error message, it tells you where it is)

Change line 127 from:
add_spec gemspec if gemspec

to:
        Gem::Specification.add_spec gemspec if gemspec

rubygems will now use the non-depreciated method and the warning should be gone.

Warning Will Robinson: I am a cowboy coder and have no idea what side effects this could have, but so far it works ok for me.  It appears that source_index.rb file is not part of the rubygems github repository, so I am guessing it is created by some other process.  I heard if you are using rails 3 this goes away.  ::shrugs::

Comment: After a little more googling, I suspect this problem stems from the system rubygems that comes pre-installed on mac.   http://opensource.apple.com/source/RubyGems/RubyGems-17/rubygems/lib/rubygems/source_index.rb    It's possible that uninstalling rubygems all together and then re-installing from the rubygems source on github may solve this. I can't risk my dev environment right now to try though.